# transferring all photos via Shared library method (failed)

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

I have a google account with domain @gmail.com    Let this be account A

I have an google workspace account with domain @somedomain.com    Let this be account B.

I would like to transfer all photos from A to B.

So I create shared library in A. and give access to B.

And then in B, I set it to save the whole library automatically.
( 1. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/36737465/130931898-11b4b0ba-171b-4c24-818c-5f98b0042428.png ) ( 2.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h6ob.png )

And then in A,  I kick the B out of the shared library.

Then log in B, I could see photos in shared library are transferring directly to B from A. However, **photos more than 2 years ago isnt there.**

So I would like to know why?